# Selenium text not working

Tags: python, selenium

I have this span tag:

```
<span class="pricefield" data-usd="11000">$11,000</span>
```

And I want to get the text for it (`$11,000`). Naturally I should be using `text` like so:

```
# empty
print self.selenium.find_element_by_css_selector(".pricefield").text
```

But it prints nothing.

This doesn't work either:

```
# None
print self.selenium.find_element_by_css_selector(".pricefield").get_attribute("text")
# None
print self.selenium.find_element_by_css_selector(".pricefield").get_attribute("value")
```

However, I can get the elements attributes just fine:

```
# 11000
print self.selenium.find_element_by_css_selector(".pricefield").get_attribute("data-usd")
```

Why doesn't this work? Did something change in Selenium? I am using 2.52.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`get_attribute("textContent")` or `get_attribute("innerText")` are the attributes you are looking for.